# Writing Excel file with Java

Tags: java, excel, spring, file, response

I am writing a functionality to write and save Excel file.

In the first case, the code is working and properly saving a valid .xlsx file in Eclipse folder (however it overwrites previous file if used again).

However, I wanted a file to be downloaded directly to a user's "Downloads" folder and if used again new file would save with name like `name(1)` etc. so I wrote some other code. It seems to be all right, but there is no effect - Excel file is nowhere to be found.

Maybe I am missing some dependency, some header - I really cannot figure this out.

**first code (working):**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exportToExcel", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={MEDIA_JSON_UTF8})
public void getExcel(@RequestParam(value="ids") List<Long> ids, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IOException {

   List<Issue> list = issueDao.getIssuesByIdsList(ids);
            
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Issues");
 
   writeHeaderLine(sheet, workbook);
   writeDataLines(list, workbook, sheet);
            
   File currDir = new File(".");
   String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
   String fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + "wycofania.xlsx";
 
   FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
   workbook.write(outputStream);
   workbook.close();
}
```

**second code (not working):**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exportToExcel", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={MEDIA_JSON_UTF8})
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getExcel(@RequestParam(value="ids") List<Long> ids, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IOException {

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   ByteArrayInputStream in;

   try {
        
      in = excelService.export(ids);
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=issues.xlsx");
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");    
      return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(new InputStreamResource(in));

   } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
      return null;
   }
}


public ByteArrayInputStream export(List<Long> ids) throws IOException {

   List<Issue> list = issueDao.getIssuesByIdsList(ids);
            
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Issues");
 
   // two lines below work well
   writeHeaderLine(sheet, workbook);
   writeDataLines(list, workbook, sheet);
            
   ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   workbook.write(outputStream);
   workbook.close();
   return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

So, in the 2nd case nothing is downloaded. No exception is thrown. The response in the 2nd case is very strange, maybe encoding problem, maybe something else:

```
PK�
Q_rels/.rels���J1�����Ͷ��4�E��D����n��LH�u��/j킂�d2�����vu��=˪E���5�\܁ʂ�����(�vs}�~��4��Ǭ
%d�H��:ێF�G
��pQ�1�:���%���[��2���v�@ڹ%�=����4�7N�+s_p)�"�&���[z`{)ȅ����lV�6��S�ҋ1��MB��[Ē@I|��Y��N��Mj~4z$A���J��.��wPKS;�VPK�
Q[Content_Types].xml�SMO1���6��m��1���G%@mgنn�t
¿wZ0F�C8M'��{��v4^��ZBD�]Æ|�*p�k�f
{�>׷��$���;h����//F�u�h�aú��:�%r�����Dm�� �\�@\7By���:e
�������
(...)
```

Edit: my Maven dependencies added for this functionality:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: #2 `produces={MEDIA_JSON_UTF8}` but outputs `application/octet-stream`: it seems that `MEDIA_JSON_UTF8` wins

Comment: Thanks. Good catch. Changed the code but the effect is the same :(

Comment: did you empty the browser's cache before download retrying? Stupid question but can be the cause - unrelated but not-minor issue: remember to close the FileOutputStream

Comment: Yeah, cache are emptied. In the first case (the working one) FileOutputStream is closed, in the second case I use ByteArrayInputStream